# Tool for getting a URL that will make my browser POST to a different URL

Tags: post, web, get

I remember that a few months ago I saw a tool that would solve a problem I have right now.

I want a URL, that when I will access it with my browser (i.e. with a GET request), it will automatic make my browser "submit" a POST form to a specified URL with specified POST data. All of this data will naturally be encoded in GET variables to the original URL. (To clarify, I don't want an AJAX request, I want the browser to actually go to the POST URL.)

I remember there being a tool for this. I could write my own, but maybe someone remembers the name/URL of the existing tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done: https://github.com/cool-RR/get_to_post (Not documented at all, use at your own risk.)